# Laravel 5 login error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was using the same below method to log-in a user.

But when I accidentally roll-back the migrations and then doing `migrate` now I registered a user successfully but can't log-in one with correct credentials.

Controller code:

```
public function index()
    {
        $cred = Input::only('username','password');
        if(Auth::attempt($cred)){
          return Redirect::intended('index');
        }else{
          $error = "Username or password is incorrect.";
          return Redirect::to('login');
        }
    }
```

When I enter the correct credentials. The login page just reloads.

Comment: debug the value of $cred what it gives

Comment: Which migration did you roll-back - all? Have you created the user again after migration was re-run?

Comment: Yes i rolled-back all and the migrated and also created the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have few thing to fix. if you follow this I think it will solve your issue, if that is not the case let me know so I can check it further:

You need to have 2 methods, one to view the form and the other to receive the form data for logging process.

I assume your index receive the data from submit from, you need to pass the submitted value username or email and password to your controller like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
```

Your input should be as array like:

```
$cred = array(
    'username' => $request->get('username'),
    'password' => $request->get('password')
);
```

Remember to add `use\Auth;` in the top of the page where other but under `namespace`.

The other thing to remember is that in Laravel 5, the default authentication uses email not username. Therefore try to change user to email like:

```
'email' => $request->get('email'),
```

Last thing, you can make a direct test by putting your login info directly in the code just to test if it works like:

```
'email' => 'my@email.com',
'password' => 'myPassword'
```

and you can always `var_dump` results like

```
var_dump($cred);
```

Have you checked if the created username and password that you are trying to login with is existing?